# Sending Files through Kafka

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

We are using Kafka streams to send image files from one web service to other to maintain persistency. During the process we convert image into array of bytes and then convert them into Base64 encoded string and send it as a message along with other file metadata. Due to large image file size our Kafka is going down.

Is there any better option to stream these images through Kafka along with the file metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use `compression` of data by the Kafka producer. Spring Cloud Stream Kafka binder allows specifying the compression type using the property: `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.producer.compressionType`

This property accepts `snappy` and `gzip` as values for compression and `none` for no compression (which is default).

Comment: Thanks Gopi! Do you also have sample code for posting file from kafka producer and receiving the same from consumer?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I don't have an example for it now. But, once the kafka producer is configured with the compression type, the consumer decompresses based on the compression type set.